# Iterate array containing custom index

Tags: arrays, for-loop, indexing, iteration, angular8

I am doing a small project in Angular8 and i have an array which contains data of users as object. This array is provided to me by the client which i can not change.

```
[
 {
  id:045#71, 
  name:'Ahmad', 
  isActive: false
 },

 {
  id:047#71, 
  name:'John', 
  isActive: false
 },
 {
  id:048#71, 
  name:'Doe', 
  isActive: false
 }
]
```

In this array i have id's as **custom indexes** because of which i am not able to iterate this array. I am getting **undefined** in console when i try to iterate the array . Is there a way to iterate array with custom indexes. I even tried forEach loop but it is not working as well.

The method i used:

```
usersArray = [
 {
  id:045#71, 
  name:'Ahmad', 
  isActive: false
 },

 {
  id:047#71, 
  name:'John', 
  isActive: false
 },
 {
  id:048#71, 
  name:'Doe', 
  isActive: false
 }
];

ngOnInit() {
this.usersArray.forEach((user)=>{
    console.log(user.id + ' - ' + user.name);
})
}
```

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: **Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token** @Supercool.

Comment: Will you please include the code that you have tried so far?

Comment: What method are you using to fetch the data ? http get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have is what we typically call a collection. You can access an item from the collection if you know its index. In most cases, the index is an integer greater or equal to zero. i.e. `collection[0]` will give you the first item.

You can use `collection.find(el => el.id ==='045#71')` to find an element in the collection, if it doesn't exist will return `undefined`.

To find the index of an item you can use `collection.findIndex(el => el.id ==='045#71')`, in this case it will return `0`

If you want to use customer indexes you would have to convert the collection into an object that uses your custom indexes as keys. There's surprisingly also a way to use custom keys in an array but it's not common practice in JavaScript.